# How to deal with job submission error in IBM?

Tags: programming, qiskit, circuit-construction, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

I keep on getting this error no matter how many circuits I run in the backend 'ibmq_athens'. It says 'Max retries exceeded with URL'. Can someone explain why I am getting this error message.

The main error message is as follows:

IBMQBackendApiError: 'Error submitting job: 'HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'s3.us-east.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /us-east-quantum-computing-user-jobs-prod/qObject-5ffc48c0c3d09157546c8092.json?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=21ce861c64cc417e9a95f95263ecf8f7%2F20210111%2Fus-east%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210111T124657Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=6715779f30e144ac7e6e1f8ae316960473e57b251c6360b02d881fb8e9a47333 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(60, \'ETIMEDOUT\')")))''

Comment: I don't think this is because the number of circuits you submitted... is it possible to post your code? so maybe someone here can try to recreate your error and fix it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is duplicate of [Error while trying to execute the Quantum Circuits in IBMQ](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14824/error-while-trying-to-execute-the-quantum-circuits-in-ibmq) . It's caused by your ISP blocking IBM Cloud object storage URL (used by IBM Q).

My answer from the other post:

This is caused by `safebrowse.io` blocking the url and sending back a http response (which the client interpreted as a TLS version it didn't understand). Unfortunately safebrowse.io doesn't allow whitelisting a single url, so you'll need to disable it entirely. Here’s a link on how to do it: [https://howtoremove.guide/safebrowse-io-virus/#:~:text=What%20is%20Safebrowse.io%3F,compromise%20their%20system%20and%20privacy](https://howtoremove.guide/safebrowse-io-virus/#:%7E:text=What%20is%20Safebrowse.io%3F,compromise%20their%20system%20and%20privacy)

Comment: note that you can *flag* questions as duplicate if you believe they are so